# How add event listener to window only if form has been changed

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

As many forms, users can accidentally click on some links when filling the fields.

But if they not fill anyone I don't need to prevent your unload.

How add event `onbeforeunload` to the `window` object only if form has been changed?

Comment: You don’t add conditionally, you add the event listener and put the condition _in the function_.

Comment: can help me with the function?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this , if you have jQuery , you can block all the link's (a) click , if user didn't fill anything .

```
function fillCheck(){
    return /* filled? (true or false) */;
}

$('body').on('click','a',function(){
    isFill =  fillCheck();
    if(!isFill){
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: The body of `fillCheck` can be easily reduced to `return /*filled?*/;`.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event first and check if the form has changed.

Sample Code:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    var formChanged = $(".name").val(); // This is example. Make any boolean value.
    if (formChanged) {
        return 'Dialog text here.';
    }
};
```

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: i need a solution without jquery to get the boolean `formChanged`, can help me? i'm not getting

Comment: jQuery is not a constraint. You can use: document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].value